# Laravel 8 API REST Login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Hi there guys I'm having a little trouble making API with Laravel 8 it seems like my auth()->attempt don't understand my $data here's the part of my code that I'm doing, I'm not using the table Users, I'm using the table Usuarios, it's already set in providers that it should see my class Usuario can you see what I'm not seeing?

```
public function registrar(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'nome' => 'required|min:4',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'senha' => 'required|min:8',
        'telefone' => 'required|min:8'
    ]);

    $user = Usuario::create([
        'nome' => $request->nome,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'senha' => Hash::make($request->senha),
        'telefone' => $request->telefone
    ]);

    $token = $user->createToken('LaravelAuthApp')->accessToken;

    return response()->json(['token' => $token], 200);
}

/**
 * Login Req
 */
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $data = [
        'email' => $request->email,
        'senha' => $request->senha
    ];
    //dd($data);
    //$credentials = request('email','senha');
    dd(Auth::attempt($data));
    if (!Auth::attempt($data)) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorised'], 401);
    } else {
        $token = auth()->user()->createToken('LaravelAuthApp')->accessToken;
        return response()->json(['token' => $token], 200);
    }
}
```

And here it is my model if it's helpful

```
<?php

      namespace App\Models;

      use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
      use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
      use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
      use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
      use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

      class Usuario extends Authenticatable
     {
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

    const TIPO = ['adm','usuario'];
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'nome',
        'tipo',
        'email',
        'senha',
        'telefone',
        'imagem',
        'cpf',
        'rg',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'senha',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verificado' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function membro(){
        return $this->hasMany(Membro::class);
    }

    public function ingresso(){
        return $this->hasMany(Ingresso::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```php
 $data = [
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->senha
    ];
```

as `attempt()` function look for `email` and `password` key

and change the database `password`

### Or

you can manually login via `auth()->login($user);` function

```php
$user = Usuario::where('email',$request->email)->first();
if(!$user){
    return response()->json(['error' => 'user not found.'], 401);
}

if (!Hash::check($request->senha,$user->senha)) {
    return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorised'], 401);
} else {
    auth()->login($user);
    $token = auth()->user()->createToken('LaravelAuthApp')->accessToken;
    return response()->json(['token' => $token], 200);
}
```

Comment: I got this before, but I don't want to modify my database, I want it in my native language but either way the second way is very handy for sure :D